# How to replace an item in a list with a dataframe column if column contains the item

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a list:

```
mylist=["one","two","three","slgrmff","signaff","huslness"]
```

and a dataframe:

```
    busy        quicksilver sign
0   huslness    qulzkslwx   slgrmff
1   NaN         NaN         signaff
```

I am trying to replace items in mylist if with the column name in the dataframe, if the column has the item.

My expected output is: `["one","two","three","sign","sign","busy"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for (i,item) in enumerate(mylist):
    for col in df.columns:
        if item in df[col].tolist():
            mylist[i]=col
```

I am sure their are more pythonic ways to do it, but this do the job!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a dictionary. This may be more efficient than looping through a dataframe each time and comparing to a list.

```
d = {}

for col in df:
    d.update(dict.fromkeys(df[col].dropna().unique(), col))

mylist=["one","two","three","slgrmff","signaff","huslness"]

res = [d.get(i, i) for i in mylist]

# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'sign', 'sign', 'busy']
```